# Why does Windows 7 display "Set Network Location" for a certain network, even after it has been connected to N times?

Tags: windows, networking

Where N as of this post is 14. Every time it connects to this certain network, it gives the "Set Network Location" box, even though it has been answered several times. The name of the network excludes the N; it's imply NETWORKNAME, but this windows (see example) writes it as 'NETWORKNAME 14'.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate?: http://superuser.com/questions/387000/why-does-windows-7-assume-there-is-a-new-network-connection-when-connecting-to-a

Try using a static address and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Only happens with a certain (1) network, not any others. The above mentioned post explains the issue happens with all networks. But still, may be a dupe?